# Databases that have '.' instead of 'localhost' are not shown

Tags: database, powershell, localhost

I'm trying to get all ODBC connections from a specific instance. The problem is that some ODBC connections are set with ".\foo" and some with "localhost\foo". In my understanding this should be the same, but I guess it's not.
In the example code I can't define an option to handle ".\foo" and "localhost\foo" as the same.

Is there a way to get all no matter if ".\foo" or "localhost\foo"?

```
Get-OdbcDsn -DsnType System -DriverName "SQL Server" | ? {
    ($_.Attribute["Server"] -eq "§\SQLServer2012")
}
```

`§` represents either `.` or `localhost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 comparisons:

```
Get-OdbcDsn -DsnType System -DriverName 'SQL Server' | ? {
    $_.Attribute['Server'] -eq '.\SQLServer2012' -or
    $_.Attribute['Server'] -eq 'localhost\SQLServer2012'
}
```

or use a regular expression match to cover both:

```
Get-OdbcDsn -DsnType System -DriverName 'SQL Server' | ? {
    $_.Attribute['Server'] -match '^(\.|localhost)\\SQLServer2012$'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Both solution were very helpful!